# C# EPPlus delete row from excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm currently working with an Excel file that has leading rows that have information I don't need.  These extra rows also mess with importing that data in the header row below.  So I'm trying to remove them to work with the data.

```
using (var pack = new ExcelPackage(myFileInfo))
{
    // Should return the sheet name
    var ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
    // Should Delete rows 1-5 and shift up the rows after deletion
    ws.DeleteRow(1,5,true);
}
```

I was thinking something like the above would work, but I've not had much success with it.

The goal would be to delete rows 1-5, shift up the rest of the data (maybe a merge would work?) then convert it into a datatable.

Anyone have tips tips or resources on removing rows from my excel sheet (prior to moving it into a datatable since that is where the issue occurs)

Comment: sounds like you need to use a foreach for starters.. do a google search on `C# EPPLUS Delete row from excel`

Comment: @MethodMan I don't believe I need to use a Foreach since the [docs](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet/M/DeleteRow) show that I can delete and shift up it seems.

Comment: then where in your code are you using the proper method overload to delete the row from the [EPLUS Documentation DeleteRow method](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet/M/DeleteRow)

Comment: Just add the parameters 1,5 => DeleteRow(1,5)

Comment: @CSharpie I'm fairly close with that suggestion currently I'm trying to figure out why my variable ws is null.  
var ws = myExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

Should give it a proper value I would assume...

Comment: you need to update your code in the original question to reflect any of your current / future questions...

Comment: @MethodMan See update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code as you have it will remove the first 5 rows but you also need to do something with the amended file. You could save it in place with:

```
pack.Save();
```

or save to a new location with:

```
pack.SaveAs(new FileInfo(outputFilePath));
```

I have uploaded a complete example [here](https://github.com/stewart-r/EpplusDeleteExample):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myFileInfo = new FileInfo("Demo.xlsx");
    using (var pack = new ExcelPackage(myFileInfo))
    {
        var ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
        ws.DeleteRow(1, 5, true);
        pack.SaveAs(new FileInfo("output.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

If you build and run the solution you can see that it transforms the demo file from this in the input file (Demo.xlsx):

[image: input file screengrab]

to this in the output file:

[image: output file screengrab]

with the first 5 rows removed and everything shifted up.