# EPPlus, delete row and image in this row

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(wb_path)))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[ws_name];
    ws.DeleteRow(3,1,true);
    pck.Save();
}
```

This does not delete image located in this row. The image is a small icon, fit within a cell. If row is deleted manually in Excel, then it's gone with the row.

I thought about manually deleting all images of the row first and then deleting the row itself but...

```
 ws.Drawings.Where(r => r.From.Row == 3 && r.To.Row == 3).ToList().ForEach(r => ws.Drawings.Remove(r));
```

...this proceeds to remove one image and then falls into System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: this linke solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981224/c-sharp-epplus-delete-row-from-excel-sheet

Comment: hardly, the question is specifically about image not being deleted, not the row not being deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an EPPlus bug. I ended up with a VBA macro, which deletes rows based on indexes provided. It also seems that Application.ScreenUpdating must be set to True in order for images to be deleted properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an issue of EpPlus. If you can delete one, and cannot delete another, there may be some index problems.

You can try reversing the list and deleting in reversed order.

```
ws.Drawings
    .Where(r => r.From.Row == 3 && r.To.Row == 3)
    .Reverse()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => ws.Drawings.Remove(r));
```

If you want to investigate further, you can check the source code from GitHub.

This is the ExcelDrawings class in EPPlus.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelDrawings.cs